# Dynamic rails controllers and views without any code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am looking for ways to reduce the default code for models, controllers and views.

I have just created a model SearchDescription with two fields and with a controller and view. I need the default scaffolded index,show etc. Also the rspecs, but again completely default. Nothing special. Just the default.

But as it turned out I am current committing some 20 files that are with a completely default behaviour. Nothing special.

Is there a way to do it cleaner with less code actually being generated in the project, but rather "dynamically generated"?

For example just write the following thing in a config file:
SearchDescription, field1, field2; with Controller; with views; with rspecs

and have this work by convention without actually generating the files?

Comment: there are lots of tools for this, but generating the boilerplate is a rails best-practice. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_controller_abstractions

Answer (score 0):

Rails is all about readability, convention over configuration and about showing others code that is self-documentary. Although ... I've done testing in this way before, although we ended up using kind of the same functions and relayed them over the files that had to be there anyway to keep it clear for anyone to read.

The spec part might look something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Initializing a 'config'-Hash that we can easy read and manipulate:

```
objectHash = {  'controller' => 'ClassController', 
          'object' => 'Class',
          'engine' => 'Engine'
        }

hash = { "#{objectHash['engine']}::#{objectHash['object'].capitalize}" => objectHash }


hash.each do |key, values|

describe Object.const_get("#{values['engine']}::#{values['controller']}"), :type => :controller do
  login_user

  before :each do
    @object_string = "#{values['engine']}::#{values['object']}"
    @object = FactoryGirl.create(Object.const_get(@object_string))
    @example_attribute = :objectAttribute
  end
```

This is the usual rails-way, just a little bit more abstract.

```
  context "GET 'index'" do
    it "should not be possible to access without permission" do
      get :index, { use_route: values['engine'].to_sym }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(302)
    end

    it "should be possible to access with permissions" do
      permission_string = "#{values['engine'].downcase}_#{values['object'].underscore.pluralize.downcase}_index"
      create_permissions(permission_string, false, true, subject.current_user)

      get :index, { use_route: values['engine'].to_sym }
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end
  end
end
```

and so on...

As you might imagine, this kind of code really breaks out of the "easy to understand" guidelines, we're all trying to follow.

And last you said you're writing tests for basic functionality? Does that really make sense to test the thing's you're aware of function anyway? I don't know exactly but it sounds like you're testing base-rails.

Comment: I would like to have the test in case I have to change something and would like to catch potential regressions.